# How can I further reduce my Apache Spark task size

Tags: scala, apache-spark, task, rdd

I'm trying to run the following code in scala on the Spark framework, but I get an extremely large task size (8MB)

```
tidRDD:RDD[ItemSet]
mh:MineHelper
x:ItemSet
broadcast_tid:Broadcast[Array[ItemSet]]
count:Int

tidRDD.flatMap(x => mh.mineFreqSets(x, broadcast_tid.value, count)).collect()
```

The reason I added the `MinerHelper` class was to make it serialisable, and it only contains given method. An `ItemSet` is a class with 3 private members and a few getter/setter methods, nothing out of the ordinary. I feel that this is the correct way to approach this problem, but Spark thinks otherwise. Am I making some gaping errors, or is it something small that's wrong?

Here's the warning:

```
WARN TaskSetManager: Stage 1 contains a task of very large size (8301 KB). The maximum recommended task size is 100 KB.
```

Comment: How are you measuring task size?

Comment: This is returned as a warning in the Spark output

Comment: Can you post the warning?

Comment: `WARN TaskSetManager: Stage 1 contains a task of very large size (8301 KB). The maximum recommended task size is 100 KB.`

Comment: Does some members are referencing others and the task serialisation is pulling out more than expected state ?

Comment: I have no idea how I can figure that out. As I said, `MinerHelper` has one method (`mineFreqSets`) with parameters defined above, and the `ItemSet` class has 3 fields: `Array[Int] - Int - BitSet`, and some operator overloaders and getters/setters. I have no idea where the problem occurs.

Comment: How are you submitting. If you look at the code, there is more than just the task that is summed up: `Task.serializeWithDependencies(task, sched.sc.addedFiles, sched.sc.addedJars, ser)`. So, do you have any added files or added jars in your submission?

Comment: Are you sure you aren't closing over another big object? For example closing over `this` is a common mistake. Where are defined your variables `mh`, `count`, etc?

Comment: Those variables are defined in the enclosing object, but how else can this be done?

Comment: No I only use local variables in my calls. I think I found a possible problem, being that my `broadcast_tid` value is just very large, and that this causes the problem. Is there any way I can fix this?

Comment: I use mllib to train random forest model and I've seen tasks up to 25MB. It throws warnings, but it seems to be working. I'd say in case you can't configure anything or change the code, you're probably fine. At least in my case, I can't configure anything to workaround it...

Answer (score 1):

You're probably closing over `this`, forcing the whole enclosing object to be serialized.

You probably have something like the following:

```
class Foo {
  val outer = ??? 
  def f(rdd: RDD[ItemSet]): RDD[ItemSet] = {
    rdd.map(x => outer.g(x))
  }
}
```

In this case, during the serialization of the task, Spark will need the instance of the enclosing `Foo`. Indeed, when you are referencing `outer`, you really mean `this.outer`.

A simple fix is to put your outer variables in local ones:

```
class Foo {
  val outer = ??? 
  def f(rdd: RDD[ItemSet]): RDD[ItemSet] = {
    val _outer = outer         // local variable
    rdd.map(x => _outer.g(x))  // no reference to `this`
  }
}
```

Comment: No I only use local variables in my calls. I think I found a possible problem, being that my `broadcast_tid` value is just very large, and that this causes the problem. Is there any way I can fix this?